# Call C function without declaring it beforehand

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, static-linking

Short version: I would like to declare a function in the same statement that calls it. The syntax I'm looking for is something of this sort:

```
// foo is undeclared in this file, and implemented in another file
int main() {
    void* p = (cast_to_function_that_receivs_ints_and_returns_pointer)foo(1,2);
}
```

Long version:

The following code creates an obvious `implicit declaration` warning and `undefined reference` error, because of the call to `foo`:

```
// a.c
int main() {
    void* p = foo(1,2);
}
```

I add the following file to the compilation to solve the `undefined reference`:

```
// b.c
void* foo(int a, int b) {
    return (void*)0xbadcafe;
}
```

I would now like to solve the `implicit declaration`. The usual solution is to modify `a.c` to either `#include` a declaration to foo or declare it itself, something like:

```
// a.c
void* foo(int a, int b);
int main() {
    void* p = foo(1,2);
}
```

But I would rather **not declare foo**, instead modifying the line that calls foo, similar to function pointers syntax, or to the example I posted in the "short versions". Is it even possible?

Assume I am proficient in C and that I have a valid motivation - I would like to "override" the behavior of `foo` by recompiling with `-Dfoo=bar`.

Comment: "But I would rather not declare foo" --> Explain why not declare?  Otherwise _declaring_ `void* foo(int a, int b);` is the best solution.

Comment: What purpose does this serve? Why is it a request we should entertain? What does it make clearer or more efficient or better in any way?

Comment: For an explanation why I would rather not declare you can just read the last line in the question.

Comment: The last line does not explain. If `foo` is defined to be `bar`, then `bar` is called, not `foo`, and it still must be declared. This definition does not avoid the requirement to declare the function that is called; it merely calls a different function, which must still be declared.

Comment: If you actually **have** some pointer to a function, and it is not the right type for the function it points to (*e.g.*, you are writing an interface with a generic or flexible function pointer), then you can cast the pointer to the desired type and call it. But that is not a matter of “declaring” the function identifier. It is a conversion.

Comment: If that is not the problem you are working on, then you should update the question with more information, including particularly the situation for which you are attempting this “declaration” as a solution.

Comment: imagine `foo` being a function I want to mock in a unit-test, and `bar` being its mock. In any case, you can focus on the question about a possible feature of C instead.

Comment: What is the difference between modifying the source file, which you would rather not do, and modifying the line the function is called on? Modifying the line the function is called on does modify the source file. So how is that acceptable when modifying the source file is not?

Comment: For instance, when you perform tests, you would rather modify the compilation line than modify the source file.

Comment: @NadavS If you pass `-Dfoo=bar` on the command line, it will change both the declaration and the reference.  It should work.  Have you tried it?

Comment: but then `bar` is implicitly declared. I would like to use `-Dfoo=(special_cast_syntax)bar`, and the question asks whether `special_cast_syntax` even exists.

Comment: This seems like an X-Y problem. If what you want to do is to be able to mock `foo` without modifying the source code, that would be a reasonable question to ask. (There's no mechanism which will work in every case, but since you seem to be prepared to place ugly casts in your source code, you can probably live with some source restrictions like "you can't mock static functions".) In any case, the point is to focus on what you want to do rather than forcing the solution to be something which is unlikely to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, your motivation is that you have existing code that looks like

```
p = bar(1,2);
```

and you would like to define macros so that it calls `foo(1,2)` instead. But you don't want to modify the source file to include a declaration of `foo` - you want to do everything by means of command-line macro definitions.  Have I got that right?

Since you've tagged this [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc), perhaps you are willing to consider non-standard gcc extensions to the C language.  If so, you can do it with gcc [statement expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html), also supported by clang and icc.  Define `bar` to expand to an expression containing a block which declares `foo` and whose value is a pointer to `foo`.  That is:

```
#define bar ({ extern void *foo(int, int); foo; })
```

Or from the command line:

```
gcc -D'bar=({ extern void *foo(int, int); foo; })'  call_bar.c
```

[Try it on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/UhP4xi).

This has

A variant would be to define a macro `bar(a,b)` with two arguments, where the corresponding statement expression actually calls `foo`:

```
gcc -D'bar(a,b)=({ extern void *foo(int, int); foo((a), (b)); })' call_bar.c
```

but this will fail if the original code tries to call `p = (bar)(a,b)` or tries to take the address of `bar`.

I'm not aware of any way to get this exact effect in standard C.  But a  different approach would be to create a header file containing the declaration of `foo`, and then using `-include` to "inject" it at the top of the source file:

```
gcc -include declare_foo.h -Dbar=foo call_bar.c
```

This isn't technically what you asked for, because at some level it does involve declaring `foo` "beforehand", but it may still help solve your problem.  In this case everything is standard C, but we have moved the "non-portability" from the code to the build process.

---

On the other hand, if the desired replacement for `bar` is something simple enough to put in a macro, like the constant return in your example, then you can cut out the middleman `foo` and just define a macro:

```
gcc -D'bar(a,b)=((void *)0xbadcafe)' call_bar.c
```

Comment: Despite not directly answering my (probably unanswerable) question, both of these answers are very helpful! I personally did not even think about defining a function macro, and didn't know about the flag `-include`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way around the declaration requirement.  You must define a symbol for the compiler to work with.  Some compilers allow you to use a pragma or other non-standard feature to create the mapping between the symbol and physical/virtual address.

Compile your mock_foo.c file and link the object file to the program instead of foo.c.

Another approach is only ever call through a macro definition:

```
#ifdef MOCK_FOO
  #define (FOO(a, b) mock_foo(a, b))
#else
  #define (FOO(a, b) foo(a, b)
#endif
```

Otherwise, you have to understand how the compiler/linker and OS/loader work, to correctly hook functions to call mocks.  There's a reason tooling for quality mock frameworks cost so much money.  They are very complex.

Comment: Disheartening answer, but expected. I will indeed work-around with a simple proxy to the dynamic library that implements the function I want to override, luckily that is the case for me..

Comment: Buyers remorse is not limited to automobile purchases.  In this particular case however, I can't think of a single programming language that has found a better solution to this problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can cast a function as you call it:

```
void *p = ((void *(*)(int, int))foo)(1, 2);
```

It's ugly, I don't see a valid reason for it, but you can.

Comment: Have you tested this?  I would expect an undeclared identifier error.  This doesn't solve the problem, since this should by pass implicit declarations.

Comment: This is not the correct answer - `foo` is not a variable, and cannot be casted.

Comment: Ah good, point, the implicit declaration is only done for function calls.